# Using special characters as keywords in latex listings package

Tags: latex, keyword, listings

I am using the listings package for latex.  I am using the SQL language definition and am adding some new keywords that I need, using morekeywords=.

I have trouble defining some special characters as keywords, for example, I need 
[], <>, &, and -> 
to be considered as keywords and use the keyword style.

I have tried adding these verbatim or with a preceding backslash.
It did not work.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try making those characters to normal letters via `alsoletter={yourcharacters}`. Later you can specify the special characters as keywords inside `morekeywords`.

Here is some code:

```
\lstset{
...
alsoletter={.},
...
}

\begin{lstlisting}[morekeywords={this.is.a.string.with.dots}]
```

Comment: Using the `otherkeywords={}` command might work for some people as well. The command _"Defines keywords that contain other characters, or start with digits."_ and _"is designed to define
keywords like =>, ->, -->, --, ::, and so on."_. See [the documentation](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) on page 45.